# Query a table then grab all rows from another table that correspond to that query

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have two tables `Invoice` and `Invoice Item`. Each entry in `Invoice Item` has the attribute `parent` where the data corresponds to the `name` attribute in `Invoice`.

What I want to do is query an invoice from `Invoice` then grab all of the items from `Invoice Item` that correspond with that invoice.

I'm currently selecting all from `Invoice` then looping through that to grab all the items in `Invoice Item`.

I have to imagine there's a much better way to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `join` keyword. Try:

```
Select *
from Invoice i
inner join InvoiceItem ii on i.name = ii.parent
order by i.name
```